# Is there a way to specifiy the base type of a generic function?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Is there a way to specify the generic type `T` to be an Object, i.e. **not** a primitive like number or string?

E.g. this clone function should only allow Objects as input because it will destructure `o`, set the prototype back to that of the original Object and return that.

```
export function clone<T>(o: T): T {
  return Object.setPrototypeOf({ ...o }, o.constructor.prototype);
}
```

The linter shows the error:

> Property 'constructor' does not exist on type 'T'

Comment: `function clone<T extends object>(o: T): T { ... }` with a lowercase `o`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `object` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-2.html#object-type) (notice the lowercase `o`) was introduced specifically to match "non-primitive" types; that is, `object` is essentially the complement of `string | number | bigint | boolean | symbol | undefined | null`.

[Don't confuse it with `Object`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#number-string-boolean-symbol-and-object) (with an uppercase `O`), which refers to anything which can be *indexed into* like an object, and is essentially the complement of `undefined | null`.  After all, a string like `"foo"` has an apparent `toUpperCase()` method; when you call `"foo".toUpperCase()` it wraps `"foo"` in a `String` object.  If you want to exclude primitives like `string`, you want `object` and not `Object`.

Anyway, that means `clone()`'s call signature should look like this:

```
export function clone<T extends object>(o: T): T {
  return Object.setPrototypeOf({ ...o }, o.constructor.prototype);
}
```

By [constraining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) the type parameter `T` to `object`, you will allow only non-primitive parameters for `o`:

```
clone(new Date()); // okay
clone({ a: 1, b: 2 }); // okay
clone([1, 2, 3]); // okay
clone("oops"); // error
clone(123); // error
clone(false); // error
clone(Symbol("wha")); // error
clone(undefined); // error
clone(null); // error
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/EQMw9mwHQC5gqgB0QUwE4GECGBnFAKASgG4AoUlAD0TDRgAIQBXAOwGMYBLMF+tgGx4oAPABV6VGChYATHPTAAjAFYoOAPnxgAXPVGFd4gN6l69NChhM0vAPIq1MKHhgAFNGDgwAnqlsh8I3ooELB6AF8AGgUoNh4cGDQmDlooRA8vXxQSUnDyASF8FhQAd3oAESwpIhJ6AHo6hQBrLG9SAuLA+ixdAEZoxV0AJgjahubW9sFOgG1++iHogGYAXTHGsBa2joJgCEQcYHWJNA80KcLeoaXj9DOLzpAsfjxb09oHggBlbwBbRTA-HwwBKAAssEc3vcdvhWDIUCBOMUZFCPjCWEx+PxUedyEA)